# Execute String in PHP

Tags: php, string, fwrite

Is it safe to write PHP code in a File and include this to get the PHP code like:

```
$fp = fopen('file.php', 'w');
$cond = 'if('.$cond.') { $cur_error = true; $error[$name] = $msg; }';
fwrite($fp, '<?php '. $cond .' ?>');
include('file.php');
fwrite($fp, '');
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: what you want to do ???

Comment: From a security perspective, even giving php write access to your site's directory is a horrible idea. An providing functionality to include user-submitted code directly into source files is asking for your site to get horrifically exploited. 0/10 Bad idea.

Comment: seems like you want to accomplish something that could be done without the file writing. care to share the general concept?

Comment: You may want to look at [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) too. It is a lot cleaner than `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()`

Comment: If what you want to accomplish is to *persist an error or other information*, you can save the code needed (here the `if`) in a file and save the required variables in session/database/memcache/data file. Conditional, *possibly user-supplied* code execution is so **not** the place to seek performance.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to execute the $cond string you can run `eval($cond)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

(But in general i would be careful with eval and file writes to the site)

Comment: aaw come on downvoters, the user obviously wants to excute a string in PHP. It might be bad practice, and ive noted that, but this is the actual answer

Comment: if someone wants to jump a building, not knowing he'll fall to death, you shouldn't help him over the ledge, but rather explain him it's rather stupid and he can better take the stairs. Or the elevator if he's lazy.